# php --version Alias setting goes wrong on Mac

Tags: php

I am developing a PHP project. I am using Mac OS X now. To be honest, this is the first time developing a PHP project using Mac. I am a Windows. I installed PHP using Brew by running the following command.

```
brew install php
```

It gave me the php latest version, 7+. For my project, I need to use php version 5.6. So, I installed another PHP by running this command.

```
brew install php56
```

Up until this point when I enter "php --version" in the terminal, it is showing that I am using php version 7+. I found some solution to change php version and so I used one of them and run this command.

```
 alias php='/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php'
```

After running that command, when I type in "php --version" in the terminal, it is showing this error.

```
-bash: /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php: No such file or directory
```

Now, I cannot use any PHP on my Mac right now. How can I fix that?

Comment: `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php` does not look like somewhere any installer would put a PHP executable.

Comment: "For my project, I need to use php version 5.6" — That version of PHP isn't really supported any more. It is only going to get security fixes until the end of the year. Doing new development with it is a **really bad idea**.

Comment: I am just making a simple change to an existing project

Comment: Where could it be? The executable? I am here struggling with Mac OSX as well.

Comment: I haven't used `brew` in years. I've no idea where it keeps its executables.

Comment: @Quentin i used it last week, and the same could be said. The eternal moving target.

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/28102

Comment: This solved the problem - alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.33/bin/php'. My laptop is now using 5.6. But when I run composer install for my project in the htdocs of MAMP, it is still using the latest 7+ version.